# Need help with Kurganov and Tadmor Central Sceme

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, hyperbolic-equations

Hi I am trying write a code for the 2nd order [Kurganov and Tadmor central scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUSCL_scheme#Kurganov_and_Tadmor_central_scheme) in order to solve Burgers' equation $u_t + u u_x = 0$. I already have written code for Lax-Friedrich and Nessyahu-Tadmor schemes, but stuck with KT (Kurganov-Tadmor) scheme due to the lacking better understanding. Can Anyone help me with any kind of materials that would help me to make an improvement in my endeavor? Thanks a lot and I highly appreciate your help.

N.B. For reference the following links have some information on that.

http://www.wikiwand.com/en/MUSCL_scheme#/Further_reading
http://www.cscamm.umd.edu/tadmor/pub/central-schemes/Kurganov-Tadmor.JCP-00I.pdf

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264273/matlab-integration-of-conservation-laws

Comment: You may have a look at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3084805/418542).